# La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta consulta

```
SELECT   
f.SE_Factura, 
SE_Consecutivo_Embarque,
f.SE_Orden_De_Compra,
f.SE_Orden_De_Venta,
f.SE_Fecha_OV,   
f.SE_Nomb_Cliente_Despachar_A,
(SELECT (f.SE_Peso*e2.SE_Cantidad_Embarcada) from SE_FactEmbarque f INNER JOIN SE_Embarques e2 ON  e2.SE_Orden_De_Venta = f.SE_Orden_De_Venta AND (e2.SE_Codigo_Articulo = f.SE_EAN_Articulo OR e2.SE_Codigo_Articulo = f.SE_Codigo_Articulo)  where e.SE_Consecutivo_Embarque = e2.SE_Consecutivo_Embarque )as Peso, +
(SELECT ((f.SE_Volumen*e3.SE_Cantidad_Embarcada))  from SE_FactEmbarque f INNER JOIN SE_Embarques e3 ON  e3.SE_Orden_De_Venta = f.SE_Orden_De_Venta AND (e3.SE_Codigo_Articulo = f.SE_EAN_Articulo OR e3.SE_Codigo_Articulo = f.SE_Codigo_Articulo)  where e.SE_Consecutivo_Embarque = e3.SE_Consecutivo_Embarque ) as Volumen    
FROM SE_FactEmbarque f  INNER JOIN SE_Embarques e ON  e.SE_Orden_De_Venta = f.SE_Orden_De_Venta   AND (e.SE_Codigo_Articulo = f.SE_EAN_Articulo OR e.SE_Codigo_Articulo = f.SE_Codigo_Articulo)  where f.SE_Factura = 'CD-40348'
```

y me regresa el siguiente error
`Mens. 512, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 1
La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza como expresión.`

Comment: suena a que todo esto: (SELECT (f.SE_Peso*e2.SE_Cantidad_Embarcada) from SE_FactEmbarque f INNER JOIN SE_Embarques e2 ON  e2.SE_Orden_De_Venta = f.SE_Orden_De_Venta AND (e2.SE_Codigo_Articulo = f.SE_EAN_Articulo OR e2.SE_Codigo_Articulo = f.SE_Codigo_Articulo)  where e.SE_Consecutivo_Embarque = e2.SE_Consecutivo_Embarque )as Peso, +
(SELECT ((f.SE_Volumen*e3.SE_Cantidad_Embarcada))  from SE_FactEmbarque f INNER JOIN SE_Embarques e3 ON  etc... as Volumen devuelve mas de un registro... para mi falta un where

Comment: Si le pongo (SELECT SUM(f.SE_Peso*e2.SE_Cantidad_Embarcada).... (SELECT SUM((f.SE_Volumen*e3.SE_Cantidad_Embarcada)).... funciona pero yo ya no necesito toda la suma si no que lo muetre individual

Comment: Uno de los selects anidados esta devolviendo mas de un registro y por eso da el error.
Prueba cada select anidado por separado como un query independiente para ver cual esta devolviendo mas de un valor y corrígelo.

Comment: Si quieres obtener valores individuales con un join sería suficiente.

Comment: Reemplaza la igualdad  `(=)` por `IN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La estructura del sub - select que utilizaste devuelve y puede devolver más de un registro siempre y cuando no estas utilizando un SUM u otro comando acumulador. Si estas buscando obtener valores individuales según la relación que hiciste podrías probar con la siguiente consulta.

```
SELECT   
   f.SE_Factura, 
   SE_Consecutivo_Embarque,
   f.SE_Orden_De_Compra,
   f.SE_Orden_De_Venta,
   f.SE_Fecha_OV,   
   f.SE_Nomb_Cliente_Despachar_A,
   f.SE_Peso*e.SE_Cantidad_Embarcada as Peso, 
   f.SE_Volumen*e.SE_Cantidad_Embarcada as Volumen    
FROM SE_FactEmbarque f  
INNER JOIN SE_Embarques e  
ON  e.SE_Orden_De_Venta = f.SE_Orden_De_Venta   
AND (e.SE_Codigo_Articulo = f.SE_EAN_Articulo OR e.SE_Codigo_Articulo = 
f.SE_Codigo_Articulo) 
where f.SE_Factura = 'CD-40348'
```